# Automating the deploy of virtual machines?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines

I was thinking to develop a tool to automatically deploy virtual machines and create a network. As a network administrator, I would like to setup a environment to test my services and to assest the security of them. Because of that, I need to create different networks with different topologies but having similar kind of systems. For example, I realized that three or four networks will have the same DNS, VPN server and same HTTP server.

Which would be, in your opinion, the best way to automatize it? Is there any tool to do this?

IF there is not any tool available, I was thinking to develop a publish–subscribe pattern where there is a main server that pushes customizatization scripts into every new system.

Would you think that this is the best approach? Or would you consider to have pre-built OVA for every system and maybe create them through some kind of manager, like VBoxManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're looking for devops tools for Infrastructure as a Code concept. There is many tools for achieve this, you can find best for your requirements.

For example

- CFEngine3 (quite difficult but can keep your instances in shape continuously)
- Ansible
- Cheff
- Puppet

Comment: Would you know if there is any opensource solution?

Comment: These are open source solutions.

Comment: these all are open source and free. At least CFEngine3 and Ansible offers paid enterprise edition with more features and support, but it is not needed in the most cases.